# Gradient over img tag using css

Tags: html, angularjs, css, gradient

I want to place a gradient over an `<img>` tag. `src` attribute of the tag is angular-item. For example:
`<img src={{value.angitem.image}}>`

I've tried to make css class:

```
.pickgradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)));
}
```

and

```
<img src={{value.angitem.image}} class="pickgradient ">
```

but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### With z-index :

You may use a container and put the gradient on that container. Then use a negative z-index to position **image behind the gradient**.

```css
.pickgradient {
  display:inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  height:200px; width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pickgradient">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HDssntn.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

### With a pseudo element :

As commented, you can also use a pseudo element with the gradient and absolute positioning to put the **gradient over the image** :

```css
.pickgradient{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.pickgradient:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

img{
  display:block;
  height:200px;width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pickgradient">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HDssntn.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can avoid negative z-index by applying the gradient to an `:after` or `:before` pseudo-element of the div.

Comment: @pstenstrm yes, that is true. Both solutions are valid and usable.

Comment: Thank you! I've modified your code like this: .pickgradient { display: inline-block; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));}
.pickgradient img{ position:relative; z-index:-1; display:block;} and used <span> instead <div>. Now it works!

Answer (score 30):

For 2020, mask-image can work well. It works in modern browsers (not IE, -webkit- prefix in many browsers currently). https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

```css
img {
   height: 200px;
   width: auto;
   mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
   -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
}
```

```html
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HDssntn.jpg" />
```

Comment: Now (end of 2023) supported in all major browsers, without a vendor prefix.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to set `background-color:black;` to your container and then set `class img{opacity:0.4}`. Then you will get the same effect as you got with

```
backgroundImage:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),url(img_url))
```

My example on Slide:

```
.Slide {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.Slide img{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try placing a `div` over the image in question and placing the gradient on the div instead of the image.